# Handle Google OAuth with JWT (react + nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, next.js, google-authentication

I am working on the authentication system of a web app, using Next.js for the client app and Node.js for the API.

- I have my Next.js app on port 3000
- I externalized the API of my application, on port 5000

That's why I used JWT for the local signin/signup strategies.
(I'm planning to use the same API for the mobile application later)

I am now wondering what is the best approch for a Google Authentication.
I have set it up, but I don't know how to give the token to the client.

Here is the process:

- On Signin page (http://localhost:3000/signin), the user clicks on "Google authentication". It redirects to 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google"
- Passport handles it, it redirects to Google OAuth page. User authorize the application.
- Google redirects to the callback URL (http://localhost:5000/auth/google/redirect)

In the callback route, I can create a JWT. But how can I give it back to the client ?
I have thought of passing it through URL, but I am wondering if it is safe ?
Is there another way to do it / Am I missing the point ?

```
router.get('/google/redirect', (req, res, next) => {
  return passport.authenticate('google', (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/signin')
    }
    console.log(user)
    // Create JWT and redirect to http://localhost:3000/signin/oauth?token=xxx ?
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

I can show more code if needed, but it works (code is not the blocking point).

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Cookie sounds like one of options. Another is a hidden input that your client reads.

Comment: @WiktorZychla My client app (Next.js) and my api (node.js) don't share the same URL. I can not create a cookie from the API and access it from the client, tha'ts why I used JWT.

Comment: CrossPOST the token then.

Comment: @Erwan what solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is setting up cookie session. When google sends responds to `/google/redirect`, `passport.authenticate` will call req.login() and this will call the `serializeUser`

```
  passport.serializeUser(
  (user, done ) => {
    done(null, user.id); // stores the id<4kb
  }
);
```

this function will create, `passport:{user:userId}`. this is the unique identifying information about the user. This where you need session. Because passport.js will automatically look for req.session and attaches the `passport`  object to the `req.session`.

Since we are storing only userId, usually cookie-session package. this package will set req.session object, passport.js will attach the `passport` object and the cookie-session will store this on the client.